# JavaScript if Statement .length not working. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this if statement i have came up with here:

```
var TotalMoney=0;
var Orbs=0;
if (TotalMoney.length==2) {
Orbs+=1;
}
```

What this code is supposed to do is if the the "TotalMoney" value digit length equals 2,
example (the number 10 has 2 digits)
then it will add 1 "Orb" to the "Orbs" value. Currently, it does nothing. There is HTML and CSS linked to this code but i figured the problem is in this code as it works fine for everything else. Please fix it as i have been trying for hours. Thanks!

For my second question that i just found out with this code here:

```
var totalMoney=0;
var orbs=0;
if (totalMoney.toString().length==2) {
orbs+=1;
}
```

This works on getting the number value digits as 2 digits long. The problem now is that once it reaches 10, every time that number goes up (10-99) all the way up, it will add 1 orb each time. I only want it to add 1 orb only when it gets to the 2 digit number (10) and stops adding 1 orb after it reaches it. How can i achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: if you want the number 10 to be equal to 2 in length.. it needs to be a STRING.. so var TotalMoney="10"; TotalMoney.length==2

Comment: Please ask a new question if you want to ask a new question to keep the answers making sense.

Comment: Duplicate of your own question… http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248311/javascript-if-statement-length-not-working-fully-why/24248613#24248613

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TotalMoney` is a number, so it doesn't have a `length` property. You can check the length of the number by first converting to a string: `TotalMoney.toString().length`.

Comment: This did it. Thank you everyone else for working answers as well. Thanks to LexJacobs for the code comments. I have another question involving this code. you will find the next question in the original answer at the top. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Number object in js has no length property, so `TotalMoney.length` return `undefined`.

If you want count digits you may use this:

```
if (TotalMoney.toString().length == 2) {
    Orbs+=1;
}
```

But if `TotalMoney` will be negative, -1 for exmple, Orbs wil be incremented.

I think there are better way to find all 2-digits number:

```
if (TotalMoney>9 && TotalMoney<100) {
    Orbs+=1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`TotalMoney` is numeric
so to find its length use this code

```
TotalMoney.toString().length;
```

Instead of

```
TotalMoney.length;
```

so try to modify your code as below:

```
var TotalMoney=0;
var Orbs=0;
if (TotalMoney.toString().length==2) {
    Orbs+=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Length is property of array & string.It can not be applied on other variables.

If you want to count number of digits you can do

```
if(TotalMoney>9)
```

Or you can convert it to string then check it's length

```
if(TotalMoney.toSting().length>2)
```

Answer (score 0):

here are some ideas and general comments on your code.

```
// recommended to start with lower case. upper case such as 'TotalMoney'
// is stylistically reserved for constructors.
var totalMoney=0; 

// again - changing form Orbs to orbs;
var orbs=0;

// recommended to use '===' until you are more experienced with JavaScript and
// know about the 'gotchas' that '==' might produce.

// you will be able to check the length of totalMoney only after converting it to a string.
if (totalMoney.toString().length === 2) {
orbs+=1;
}
```

Finally, totalMoney of 0 will not add one to orbs. But totalMoney of 10, as you mentioned, will.